# Modal "dialog" usercontrol c#

Tags: c#, windows-ce, modal-dialog

I'm working on a project to create a machine with an user interface on **Windows CE 5.0** embedded system. I'm not really good about windows form and c#. That's why i'm asking your help.

I am using user control instead of form because they were doing weird transition **on Closing and on Showing**. So I decided to use multiple user control as fullscreen tab in one main form. The problem is I must use a user control with modal behavior in some situation. I saw bunch of code for **C#**   but it was **C# WPF or ASP.NET** (i dont know if it's the same thing). So is there any way in C# to create user control acting like a modal dialog. I alerady add the showdialog function i just dont know how to block parent function when it is called.

```
public abstract partial class cDialog : UserControl, Transparency_Background // Alpha
    {

        cDialog _mFather;

        protected Bitmap _mBackgroundImage;

        public cDialog()
        {

            _mBackgroundImage= new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.logo);

            InitializeComponent();

            btn_exit.Text = Fs.mMemory.GetVocabulary(eVocabulary.X);

        }


        private void cDialog_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

            e.Graphics.DrawImage(_mBackgroundImage, 0, 0);

        }

        protected virtual void CloseDialog(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_mFather!= null)
            {

                _mFather.Show();

                _mFather.TopLevelControl.Controls.Remove(this);
            }

        }

        public virtual void ShowDialog(cDialog father)
        {

            _mFather = father;

            if (_mFather!= null)
            {
                _mFather.TopLevelControl.Controls.Add(this);

                this.BringToFront();

                base.Show();

                _mParent.Hide();
            }

       }


        protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            //Do nothing Double buffering See Alpha.cs
        }
```

Sorry for my english
Thanks in advance, 
Alex.

Comment: A modal dialog should *look* like a dialog so that the user knows that trying to activate other windows cannot work.  Only using Form.ShowDialog makes sense.  If you want to trap the user in a box then just set the Enabled properties to false.

Comment: If I cant use it as dialog, is there any other way I could stop the executing code until the usercontrol is closed or disable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a different solution than make my user control modal. I decide to add a new class in **cDialog** where:

```
public abstract class cSubExecutionDialog
{
      public abstract UpdateParent();
}
```

and i added in my dialog close method:

```
protected virtual void CloseDialog(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (_mFather!= null)
     {

         _mFather.Show();

         _mFather.TopLevelControl.Controls.Remove(this);

         _mFather.SubExe.UpdateParent();

      }


}
```

So before i call onShow() , i create a child class of cSubExecution Dialog and it use is own updateParent onClose(). Finally it prevent the execution of the code continue until the user control is closed.